# Trouble in comparison JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask

I have to implement a web service using Flask and MongoDB. I have two collections. The JSON files are shown below:

***File products.json:***

```
{ "name":"red apples", "price":0.5, "description":"Apples from Greece", "category":"fruits", "stock":25 }
{ "name":"fish", "price":5, "description":"Fresh fish", "category":"fish", "stock":25 }
{ "name":"pasta", "price":1.5, "description":"Pasta from Italia", "category":"pasta", "stock":25 }
```

***File users.json:***

```
{"name":"George Vaios", "password":"321", "email":"george@gmail.gr", "category":"admin"}
{"name":"Admin", "password":"admin", "email":"admin@gmail.gr", "category":"admin"}
```

**What I'm trying to do?**
I'm trying to implement a function called `add_product`. This function allows users whose category is admin (`"category": "admin"`). As a route has a POST method because I'm parsing the `email` of a user and the details are needed to import a new product in `products.json`.

**Code:**

```
(lines of code for loading data)
user = users.find_one({"email":data['email']})
   if (user['category']=="admin"):
      product = {
         "name": data['name'],
         "price": data['price'],
         "description": data['description'],
         "category": data['category'],
         "stock": data['stock']
      }
        products.insert_one(product)
        return Response("Product was added succesfully", status=200, mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        return Response("Account has no permission. Must be an admin", status=400, mimetype='application/json')
```

With that code I'm trying to check if the user is an admin by finding him in the JSON file using the `find_one` method and then compare the `user['category']` with the string `'admin'`.

**Data that I'm parsing to postman:**

```
{
    "email": "george@gmail.gr",
    "name": "chocolate",
    "price": 25,
    "description": "mklkgj",
    "category": "sweets",
    "stock": 30
}
```

***Error that I get:***

```
File "/home/michael/main.py", line 241, in add_product_admin
    if (user['category']=="admin"):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I can't understand why the if statement doesn't make the comparison. Any thoughts?

Comment: `find_one` will return None if it doesn't find any matches, which would result in the error you are seeing when you try to subscript it.  So I'd check that user isn't None first.  And then try to figure out why find_one() wouldn't be finding what you expect.

Comment: As a side note it seems like you are trying to use "email" part of the POST payload as a mean of authorisation. I hope you realise that not only legit  owners of "george@gmail.gr" email account can submit such request.

Comment: @saquintes Hmm I understand. I checked if the collection of Users is empty in Mongo shell. Indeed has zero entries. But still can't understand why this happen. Maybe I did a mistake when I created the collections with the JSON files

Comment: @AlexBlex Yes, I understand. That's a uni project and I don't have such an experiance to avoid the authorization with better practises. That's why I'm only trying to implement this with the comparison

Answer (score 0):

Mongo is telling you that nothing came up when searching for that value. I would start by checking if data['email'] has the value you would expect and if your collection is initialized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who explained to me what's going on. The actual problem was on MongoDB and client parameters on Python script. That's why the entries and JSON files were unreadable. If anyone comes up again with this problem be sure that you have checked:

```
# Choose database
database = client['database you want to access']
```

Then don't forget to check with mongo shell if your expected collections exist:

```
db.(your database name).find({})
```

Thank you for your time!